# How To Create Total Row and Total Column to Pivot Table in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I have created a pivot table using SQL but want to add column and row totals. How am I able to achieve this using SQL. This is the following code I have for my pivot table.

```
SELECT * from 
(
    select committee, status, id from EMPLOYEES
) piv

pivot (
count (id)
for status in ('Resume Review', 'Interviewing', 'Coding Challenge', 'Hired')
) pivot_table;
```

My Current Table:

```
Committee   Resume Review   Interviewing    Take Home Challenge  
UI/UX              3             2                  1              
Finance            0             2                  2              
Marketing          2             4                  1
```

Desired Table:

```
Committee   Resume Review   Interviewing    Take Home Challenge  Total 
UI/UX              3             2                  1              6
Finance            0             2                  2              4
Marketing          2             4                  1              7
Total              5             8                  4              17
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36600457/how-to-use-rollup-rank-with-pivot-table-in-oracle11g

Answer (score 2):

If you are open to not using the `PIVOT` operator, we can use conditional aggregation to achieve your result:

```sql
SELECT
    Committee,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 'Resume Review'    THEN 1 END) AS "Resume Review",
    COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 'Interviewing'     THEN 1 END) AS "Interviewing",
    COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 'Coding Challenge' THEN 1 END) AS "Coding Challenge",
    COUNT(*) AS Total
FROM EMPLOYEES
WHERE status IN ('Resume Review', 'Interviewing', 'Coding Challenge')
GROUP BY Committee;
```

Comment: This did add a column total but do you know how I can add a row total at the bottom? Thank you for your response!

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
SELECT * from 
(
    select committee, status, id from EMPLOYEES
) piv

pivot (
count (id)
for status in ('Resume Review', 'Interviewing', 'Coding Challenge', 'Hired')
) pivot_table;

union all 

SELECT 'Total' as committee,
sum(Resume Review) as Resume Review,
sum(Interviewing) as Interviewing,
sum(Coding Challenge) as Coding Challenge,
sum(Hired) as Hired,
sum(Resume Review) + sum(Interviewing) +sum(Coding Challenge) + sum(Hired) as Total 
from 
(
    select committee, status, id from EMPLOYEES
) piv

pivot (
count (id)
for status in ('Resume Review', 'Interviewing', 'Coding Challenge', 'Hired')
) pivot_table;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation and then `ROLLUP` to get a total row and then add the column values together to get a total column:

```sql
SELECT r.*,
       resume_review + interviewing + coding_challenge + hired AS total
FROM   (
  SELECT CASE GROUPING_ID(committee)
         WHEN 0
         THEN committee
         ELSE 'Total'
         END AS committee,
         COUNT(CASE status WHEN 'Resume Review'    THEN id END) AS resume_review,
         COUNT(CASE status WHEN 'Interviewing'     THEN id END) AS interviewing,
         COUNT(CASE status WHEN 'Coding Challenge' THEN id END) AS coding_challenge,
         COUNT(CASE status WHEN 'Hired'            THEN id END) AS hired
  FROM   EMPLOYEES
  GROUP BY ROLLUP(committee)
) r
```

Or, by including all the columns in a conditional aggregation to get the column-wise totals:

```sql
SELECT CASE GROUPING_ID(committee)
       WHEN 0
       THEN committee
       ELSE 'Total'
       END AS committee,
       COUNT(CASE status WHEN 'Resume Review'    THEN id END) AS resume_review,
       COUNT(CASE status WHEN 'Interviewing'     THEN id END) AS interviewing,
       COUNT(CASE status WHEN 'Coding Challenge' THEN id END) AS coding_challenge,
       COUNT(CASE status WHEN 'Hired'            THEN id END) AS hired,
       COUNT(
         CASE
         WHEN status IN (
                'Resume Review', 'Interviewing', 'Coding Challenge', 'Hired'
              )
         THEN id
         END
       ) AS total
FROM   EMPLOYEES
GROUP BY ROLLUP(committee)
```

Or, using `PIVOT` and then aggregating and using `ROLLUP`:

```sql
SELECT CASE GROUPING_ID(committee)
       WHEN 0
       THEN committee
       ELSE 'Total'
       END AS committee,
       SUM(resume_review) AS resume_review,
       SUM(interviewing) AS interviewing,
       SUM(coding_challenge) AS coding_challenge,
       SUM(hired) AS hired,
       SUM(resume_review + interviewing + coding_challenge + hired) AS total
FROM   (SELECT committee, status, id FROM EMPLOYEES)
PIVOT  (
  COUNT(id)
  FOR status IN (
    'Resume Review'    AS resume_review,
    'Interviewing'     AS interviewing,
    'Coding Challenge' AS coding_challenge,
    'Hired'            AS hired
  )
)
GROUP BY ROLLUP(committee);
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE employees (id PRIMARY KEY, committee, status) AS
SELECT LEVEL +  0, 'UI/UX',     'Resume Review'    FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 3 UNION ALL
SELECT LEVEL +  3, 'UI/UX',     'Interviewing'     FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 2 UNION ALL
SELECT LEVEL +  5, 'UI/UX',     'Coding Challenge' FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 1 UNION ALL
SELECT LEVEL +  6, 'Finance',   'Interviewing'     FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 2 UNION ALL
SELECT LEVEL +  8, 'Finance',   'Coding Challenge' FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 2 UNION ALL
SELECT LEVEL + 10, 'Marketing', 'Resume Review'    FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 2 UNION ALL
SELECT LEVEL + 12, 'Marketing', 'Interviewing'     FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 4 UNION ALL
SELECT LEVEL + 16, 'Marketing', 'Coding Challenge' FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 1;
```

All the queries output:

> | COMMITTEE | RESUME_REVIEW | INTERVIEWING | CODING_CHALLENGE | HIRED | TOTAL |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | Finance | 0 | 2 | 2 | 0 | 4 |
> | Marketing | 2 | 4 | 1 | 0 | 7 |
> | UI/UX | 3 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 6 |
> | Total | 5 | 8 | 4 | 0 | 17 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c3ebb1da7a13353c532f657cc60d76b2)*