# How to alias ROLLUP in SQL Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am creating a pivot table using Oracle SQL where there is a total row at the bottom. It does work however the first column of the row shows as '-' whereas I'd like it to be 'Total'
This is my current code:

```
SELECT
    TEAM,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 'Idea' THEN 1 END) AS "Idea",
    COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 'Published' THEN 1 END) AS "Published",
    COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 'Submitted For Publication' THEN 1 END) AS "Submitted For Publication",
    COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 'In Progress' THEN 1 END) AS "In Progress",
    COUNT(*) AS Total
FROM TEAM_TRACKER
WHERE status IN ('Idea', 'Published', 'Submitted For Publication', 'In Progress')
GROUP BY rollup (TEAM)
```

How can I achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just use `coalesce(Team,'TOTAL')` in your select.  But this assumes each team can't be null.  Though... this type of data edit is best done in the User interface not at the data layer.

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=7766adb9f020fe78d6868bd55192c58d)

```
with CTE AS (SELECT 1 as amt, 'a' team from dual UNION ALL
SELECT 1 as amt, 'a' team from dual UNION ALL
SELECT 1 as amt, 'a' team from dual UNION ALL
SELECT 2 as amt, 'b' team from dual UNION ALL
SELECT 3 as amt, 'c' team from dual)

SELECT sum(Amt), coalesce(team,'TOTAL')
FROM CTE
GROUP BY rollup (team)
```

Giving us:

```
+----------+------------------------+
| SUM(AMT) | COALESCE(TEAM,'TOTAL') |
+----------+------------------------+
|        3 | a                      |
|        2 | b                      |
|        3 | c                      |
|        8 | TOTAL                  |
+----------+------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

If the grouping key is not NULLable simple follow the *coalesce* advice.

More secure and *designed* for this purpose is to use [`grouping_id`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/GROUPING_ID.html#GUID-E20A5B8E-73B6-42FD-8AFB-DD3CD6D6DC61) that identifies the total line

**Example**

```
create table team_tracker as
(select '1' team from dual union all
 select '1' team from dual union all
 select '2' team from dual union all
 select null team from dual);
 
select 
case when grouping_id(team) = 1 then 'Total' else team end as team,
count(*) cnt 
from team_tracker
group by rollup(team);

TEAM         CNT
----- ----------
1              2
2              1
               1
Total          4
```

Answer (score 0):

From the answer to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71524884/1509264), use `GROUPING_ID`:

```sql
SELECT CASE GROUPING_ID(team)
       WHEN 0
       THEN team
       ELSE 'Total'
       END AS team,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 'Idea' THEN 1 END) AS "Idea",
       COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 'Published' THEN 1 END) AS "Published",
       COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 'Submitted For Publication' THEN 1 END) AS "Submitted For Publication",
       COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 'In Progress' THEN 1 END) AS "In Progress",
       COUNT(*) AS Total
FROM   TEAM_TRACKER
WHERE   status IN ('Idea', 'Published', 'Submitted For Publication', 'In Progress')
GROUP BY ROLLUP(TEAM)
```